# Dynamic arguments in python write

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to build a function that dynamically deletes and orders rows based on the column numbers it is passed in. So far I have defined the following:

```
import csv

def delete(rows_to_keep):
    with open('file.csv','r') as source:
        rdr= csv.reader( source )
        with open('reordered.csv','w') as result:
            wtr= csv.writer( result, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n' )
            for r in rdr:
                wtr.writerow( ... )

rows_to_keep = [1, 3, 5, 6]

delete(rows_to_keep)
```

However, in the above, I would like the ... in the writerow(...) to be replaced by arguments as follows:

```
... = r[1], r[3], r[5], r[6]
```

i.e.

```
wtr.writerow( r[1], r[3], r[5], r[6] )
```

And have the number of arguments and order change depending what is passed in.

I am not quite sure how I could do this if suddenly the array has 10 values. Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rows_to_keep` in a loop to build a *list* with the new sequence of values you want to write out. Then pass that list to `writerow()`; it doesn't accept an arbitrary number of arguments, so you must call it with a list one way or another. Something like this:

```
rows_to_keep = [1, 3, 5, 6]
...
for row in rdr:
    newrow = list()
    for n in rows_to_keep:
        newrow.append(row[n])
    wtr.writerow(newrow)
```

PS. Or use a comprehension if you prefer. Same result (if used correctly).

```
for row in rdr:
    newrow = [row[n] for n in rows_to_keep]
    wrt.writerow(newrow)
```

Comment: I would always use a list comprehension: this is what they are for. Also, in the first example, `list()` would customarily be simply written as `[]`.

Comment: Comprehensions are great, but they're hard for new programmers to wrap their heads around. Since it's not what the question is _about,_ I chose to keep it simple and explicit. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
wtr.writerow([r[col] for col in rows_to_keep])
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, `writerow(*[r[col] for col in rows_to_keep])` is actually appropriate, in order to have the same effect as "`wtr.writerow( r[1], r[3], r[5], r[6] )`".

Comment: Not quite, @EOL: `writerow()` with multiple arguments is a syntax error. But yes, that should be `r[col]` in the comprehension.

Comment: @alexis Even if the expression that was wanted in the question is not correct, I still stand by my comment, which is arguably correct. Note that technically, the expressions do not yield not a syntax error, but a TypeError (there is nothing wrong with the syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant `columns_to_keep` and pass the list of columns to keep as a list to the function. You can use `operator.itemgetter` here

```
import csv
import operator

def prune_columns(columns_to_keep):
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as source,\
         open('reordered.csv','w') as result:
        rdr = csv.reader( source )
        wtr = csv.writer(result, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n' )

        select = operator.itemgetter(*columns_to_keep)
        # select is now a function that returns a tuple that 
        # returns elements 1, 3, 5 and 6 of the input

        for row in rdr:
            wtr.writerow(select(row))

prune_columns(columns_to_keep=[1, 3, 5, 6])
```